# How can we solve json parsing error com.eclipsesource.json.ParseException

Tags: java, json

I want create json object from string value
my String value is
`{item_type:file,item_id:1026757353679,item_name:X MIB original data_Sep2022 (Jun-Sep) in proc.xlsx,parent:{type:folder,name:KA reference only,id:175411699324},owned_by:{type:user,id:7950826893,name:Rie Tanaka,login:rtanaka@alnylam.com}`}

i am using following code in java and com.eclipsesource.json.Json
`

```
                jsonObject = Json.parse(eventJson).asObject();
```

`
i am getting error
"Expected name at 1:2
com.eclipsesource.json.ParseException: Expected name at 1:2"

Am I doing wrong? Suggest me using library only com.eclipsesource.json.Json

Comment: You cannot parse invalid json with a json parser. The error message tells you exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is not valid [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). Your keys and non-number values need to be quoted.